# How to retrieve data from array using $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, thymeleaf

I have a small web app where I need to populate a dropdown list after selecting another right before.

For example this is the URL of the Ajax request http://localhost:8080/ajax/dropdown_model?brandId=0 and the JSON code looks like this:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Z-400","brand":{"id":0,"name":"Lenovo"}}]
```

The code I used is this one:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var html = '';
     $('select#brand').change(
        function() {
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/ajax/dropdown_model", {
                brandId : $(this).val(),
                ajax : 'true'
            }, function(data) {
                html = '<option disabled="disabled" value="">Seleccionar modelo:</option>';
                var len = data.length;
                for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'
                           data[i].id + ' : ' + data[i].name + '</option>';
                }
                html += '</option>';
                $('select#model').html(html);
            });
        }); </script>
```

It should replace the content of the 2nd select tag adding into it the content of the JSON string.
Also this is the relevant part of the form (I'm using Spring and Thymeleaf):

```
<div class="brand" th:object="${lbra}">
           <select name="brand" id="brand" >
        <option value="">Seleccionar marca:</option>
        <option th:each="brand : ${lbra}"
                th:value="${brand.getId()}"
                th:text="${brand.getId()}+' : '+${brand.getName()}"></option>
    </select>   </div>

      <div class="model" id="modellist">
           <select name="model" id="model">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Seleccionar modelo:</option>
        <option></option>
    </select>   </div>
```

Comment: This question is incorrectly tagged 'java'. Java is a different language than JavaScript.

Comment: Please let me know if the below answer helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've removed some of the Spring variables for the sake of creating an example. You were missing a "+" after your dynamic option that is added to the HTML string (after `html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'`)..

```js
var html = '';
$('select#brand').change(
  function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ugf4v", {
      brandId: $(this).val(),
      ajax: 'true'
    }, function(data) {
      html = '<option disabled="disabled" value="">Seleccionar modelo:</option>';
      var len = data.length;         
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' +
          data[i].id + ' : ' + data[i].name + '</option>';
      }
      html += '</option>';
      $('select#model').html(html);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand">
  <select name="brand" id="brand">
        <option value="">Seleccionar marca:</option>
        <option>Test Change</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="model" id="modellist">
  <select name="model" id="model">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Seleccionar modelo:</option>
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad. You're right but the main problem was the document ready thing and I changed the loop for a data.for each.